# record voice call in android

Tags: java, android, record

I should record voice during call, I do it with a GIO SUMSUNG cellphone but it records voice call and microphone voice both, I mean that I have recorded both voice not only the other-party.

And in the sound I have recorded, microphone's voice is too louder than the other one.

What can I do?

Can I record only the other party voice? Or It becomes louder sound.
I did it before but today I really stuck on it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194342/how-can-i-record-voice-and-record-call-in-android

Comment: Settings
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330340/android-audiorecord-which-settings-to-record-call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929984/recording-call-help-needed

Answer (score 1):

open it

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2117#c226

Answer (score 1):

Instead of
*myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);*

use 
*myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);*

This particular option is described here> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html
Voice call uplink + downlink audio source
That means the recording will contain both voices.

Be careful when you start recording. When the call is initiated or when the other-party answer the call.