# MediaRecorder start fail

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am trying to make a voice call recorder app. But I have faceing a issue. When i am starting record the app is crashsing. It showing **MediaRecorder start failed: -2147483648**. What i can do now?

In here I am using MediaRecorder class.

I have tried this code.

```
public void startRecord(){
        String error = "";
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

        // Set the output file path
        String outputFilePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/test.mp3" ;
        System.out.println(outputFilePath);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFilePath);


        try {

            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
            mediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int i, int i1) {
                    System.out.println(mediaRecorder);
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println(i1);
                }
            });
            error = "Start Record";

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error = e.getMessage();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

    }
```

But I got this error in log of my android studio. And yes, I run it in my mobile device not in emulator.

The error is,

```
start failed: -2147483648
2023-10-15 23:05:21.957  1750-1750  AndroidRuntime          com.team71.callrecording             D  Shutting down VM
2023-10-15 23:05:21.962  1750-1750  AndroidRuntime          com.team71.callrecording             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.team71.callrecording, PID: 1750
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
                                                                                                        at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.team71.callrecording.StartRecording.startRecord(StartRecording.java:34)
                                                                                                        at com.team71.callrecording.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:60)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7505)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7477)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:824)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28652)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8218)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
```

Comment: duplicated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479041/java-lang-runtimeexception-start-failed-at-android-media-mediarecorder-startna

Comment: @Hadas brother I had tried all of those but not solve so that I have posted this.

Comment: they suggest there 2 approaches - 
1. different handling for samsung and lg devices
2. check if you declare the right permission in the manifest + ask for permission in runtime before start the recording.

Comment: @Hadas I have already done that. When i have used voice_commination there was not recording phone call voice.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource#VOICE_CALL):

> Capturing from VOICE_CALL source requires the
> Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission. This permission
> is reserved for use by system components and is not available to
> third-party applications.

In other words unless you are a system app you have to use a different source (e.g. [VOICE_COMMUNICATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource#VOICE_COMMUNICATION)).

Comment: Brother I have used the VOICE_COMMUNICATION. But I don’t able to record the caller voice. There was just my voice.

Comment: This is a different question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929984/recording-phone-calls-on-android for example.